# NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown 454 4.7.1 Relay access denied

Tags: email, sendgrid, access-denied, postfix-mta

Configured Postfix With Sendgrid. When I send mail from server i.e.root user mails are sending . but I login using mail client like thunderbird and send mail that time mails are not sending . getting error in 'RCPT from unknown 454 4.7.1  Relay access denied' .

Answer (score 2):

I've spent nearly 5 hours on this and I found this is just `mynetworks` issue. Few other posts were pointing about `relay_restrictions` but its not the case.

So, first thing is to check `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`. There everything was fine in my case.

Second, I changed `mynetworks` as

```
mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0
```

Now, its allowing me to send from everywhere (all the IP addresses). If you need to restrict to allow from particular IP try something like  below. (Replace XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX with your static ip)

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128 [2001:240:587::]/64 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Thunderbird as MUA, Postfix as MTA, Dovecot as MDA and I have same issues.
I solved adding the IP address of my home PC on mynetworks parameter on main.cf

`mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 MyIpAddress`

P.S. I don't have a static ip for my home PC so when my ISP change it I ave to adjust every time.